# Creating Strongly typed view showing big list in View data class 

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

When I am creating Strongly Typed View I get lots of Classes in View Data Drop down. Classes like Automapper, ninject, Interface..., latebound... Due this its very hard to find my project classes. Is there any way to restrict dropdown to only display my project classes?

Hope you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report. There's currently no way to customize which types appear in that dialog. In the future we might improve things by providing searching, smarter filtering, etc, but this will not happen for MVC 3 RTM.